# How to define an alias type?

Tags: stanza

A route is defined as a [String, String] tuple.
What is the most appropriate way to define type alias 'Route' as [String, String]?
e.g.

```
defn same-route? ( x : [String,String], y : [String,String] ) -> True|False :
```

I would like to use

```
defn same-route? ( x : Route, y : Route ) -> True|False :
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way would be to define a `Route` struct that wraps the Strings:

```
defstruct Route :
  start: String
  end: String
```

Inside `same-route?` you can compare the `start` and `end` fields.

```
defn same-route? (x:Route, y:Route) -> True|False :
  start(x) == start(y) and end(x) == end(y)
```

The preferred way to compare equality is to subtype `Equalable` and implement the `equal?` method:

```
defstruct Route <: Equalable :
  start: String
  end: String

defmethod equal? (x:Route, y:Route) -> True|False :
  start(x) == start(y) and end(x) == end(y)
```

`==` is a macro for `equal?`, so this enables the following code:

```
val x = Route("San Francisco", "Madrid")
val y = Route("Paris", "New Delhi")
println(x == y)
> false
```